# Grouping polygons by nearby neighbors and by area in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis

I would like to group polygons of the same layer into groups by closer neighbors until they meet a certain area. I use QGIS 3.4. That is to say, the polygons must be united fulfilling two conditions:
1. to touch
2. That the sum of that group of polygons does not exceed more than 5 m2

[image]

Comment: Do the polygons need to touch each other or should they just be close - i.e. within a certain distance - from each other? Can just any neighboring polygon be grouped until they meet your area criteria?  (Please do not answer this comment, but elaborate your question a bit more, it is still a bit fuzzy :-) )